# Autolayout ScrollView programmatically swift

Tags: swift, xcode, uiscrollview, autolayout

I need to set the layout of a ScrollView full-screen with autolayout. at the moment I have this code but not the full-height sect and I can not understand which variable to change. I have this code

```
func setControlsType(controlsType: ControlsType, bounds: CGRect, startingDim: CGFloat, scrolledDim: CGFloat) {
    self.controlsType = controlsType
    if Utils.isInPortraitState() {
        /*self.startingFrame = CGRect(x: 0, y: bounds.height - startingDim, width: bounds.width, height: scrolledDim)
        self.scrolledFrame = CGRect(x: 0, y: bounds.origin.y + bounds.height - scrolledDim, width: bounds.width, height: scrolledDim)*/
        self.startingFrame = CGRect(x: 0, y: bounds.height, width: bounds.width, height: scrolledDim)
        self.scrolledFrame = CGRect(x: 0, y: bounds.origin.y + bounds.height, width: bounds.width, height: scrolledDim)
    } else {
        self.startingFrame = CGRect(x: startingDim - scrolledDim, y: 0, width: scrolledDim, height: bounds.height)
        self.scrolledFrame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: scrolledDim, height: bounds.height)
    }


func setControls(type: ControlsType) {
    let safeBounds = SafeAreaManager.letsDoIt(view: self, upon: .bounds)

    /*let sDim = (Utils.isInPortraitState() ?  safeBounds.height + (self.workbenchView.frame.origin.y + self.workbenchView.frame.size.height) : safeBounds.width + (self.workbenchView.frame.size.width + self.workbenchView.frame.width))*/

    let sDim = CGFloat(0)

    var scDim = CGFloat(0)

    if Utils.isIPad() {
        if Utils.isInPortraitState() {
            scDim = safeBounds.height - (self.workbenchView.frame.origin.y  + 2 * (self.workbenchView.frame.size.height/3))
        } else {
            scDim = self.workbenchView.frame.origin.x  + self.workbenchView.frame.size.width/3
        }
    } else {
        if Utils.isInPortraitState() {
            scDim = safeBounds.height - self.workbenchView.frame.size.height
        } else {
            scDim = safeBounds.width - self.workbenchView.frame.size.width
        }
    }
    self.controlsView.setControlsType(controlsType: type, bounds: safeBounds, startingDim: sDim, scrolledDim: scDim)
}
```

Comment: Why not use constraints?

Comment: I tried to use them, but these functions are recalled from other parts of the code and do not accept them. I do not know how to solve

Comment: I don't really understand what do you want to accomplish. Do you want the UIScrollView to take the full screen of your iDevice or just have the same bounds as your blue rectangular view at the bottom of your screen?

Comment: @YoanGJ sorry. I want take my scrollview to the full screen with this code, but I can't understand frame propriety.. help please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that this code is not in your view controller so I see two options among others:

1. You pass your view and your scroll view to one of your function in the file that you shared above. Then you apply contraints to your scroll view so its frame match your view frame. This function will look like this:

   ```
   func resizeScrollView(view: UIView, scrollView: UIScrollView) {
       NSLayoutConstraint(item: scrollView, attribute: .top, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: view, attribute: .top, multiplier: 1, constant: 0).isActive = true
       NSLayoutConstraint(item: scrollView, attribute: .trailing, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: view, attribute: .trailing, multiplier: 1, constant: 0).isActive = true
       NSLayoutConstraint(item: scrollView, attribute: .bottom, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: view, attribute: .bottom, multiplier: 1, constant: 0).isActive = true
       NSLayoutConstraint(item: scrollView, attribute: .leading, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: view, attribute: .leading, multiplier: 1, constant: 0).isActive = true
   }
   ```
2. Or you can access the bounds property of the screen of your device via `UIScreen` and in this case the function will look like this:

   ```
   func resizeScrollView(scrollView: UIScrollView) {
       scrollView.bounds = UIScreen.main.bounds
   }
   ```

Then you'll have to set the position of your scroll view in your view controller.